# Compute integral without using derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, exponential-function

I want to calculate the following integral without using derivatives

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b e^{ty}\,{\rm d} y$$

where $t, a, b \in \Bbb R$. I know that the result is

> $$\frac{1}{b-a} \left( \frac{e^{tb}-e^{ta}}{t} \right)$$

My first idea was to transform it into a sum:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b-a}{n}e^{t(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)}*\frac{1}{b-a} $$
But it doesn't seems to work or the transformation is wrong.Any suggestions?

Comment: It works fine. The sum is geometric so you can evaluate it and take the limit after.

Comment: What does "compute integral without using derivative" mean?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedor I would assume that the antiderivative is meant.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start where you stopped:
$$ \begin {align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{b-a}{n}e^{t(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)}\frac{1}{b-a}\\
&=e^{ta}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} e^{t\frac{b-a}{n}i}\\
&=e^{ta}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n  \frac{e^{t(b-a)}-1}  {e^{t\frac{b-a}n}-1}
\end {align} $$

Can you take it from here?